# How to increase the performance of html editor in IE browser?

Tags: extjs, html-editor

We have used htmleditor in our application. When the form is loaded every component is loaded properly. But htmleditor is taking huge amount of time to load.

Can anyone please suggest, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried loading it on a page just on its own and see if it loads faster? To help narrow down the problem.

Comment: If you load less button features it loads faster. You'll need to edit the control to only have the buttons which you require.

Comment: I would recommend you to try and use different browsers and see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

As I found on a forum:

> When I enable "CombineScripts" on the toolscriptmanager it is much
>   faster but the toolbar is not displayed.
>
> Using CSS sprites or images on a directory for the toolbar (not as
>   resources as it is now) and removing any resourcestrings will boost
>   the control speed more than 1000%! Hope someone will implement it on a
>   next version, or I will do it when I find some time.

Hope it helps you.